# Make Linux Notebook Act Like a Network Hub

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, subnet

I've been looking for a solution for this quite a while and I think that I am exactly as clueless as before. So I figured why not ask people who *really* know about this stuff...

**I'm trying to** connect a computer - which is *not* capable of WiFi - to my router. You might think "why not use wired LAN". Easy. None of my cables are long enough and I don't want to buy one because I am sure that the problem can be solved otherwise.

**So far I have got:**

- Xubuntu 14.04 Notebook with WiFi
- Windows 7 Computer with only wired NIC
- AVM Fritz.box

At the moment, I have the notebook connect to WiFi network and share its internet with the computer via cable. This works fine. Only problem is that I can't connect to the home network, making it impossible to connect to a local IP. I have to forward the ports in my Fritz.box which kinda sucks because the public IP of the router changes all the time. Now I've heard of subnetting, which should solve my problem (does it?) by joining the two networks together in a way. Something about static routes was mentioned, too. But since I slept through this class a few years ago, I don't know much about that.

So basically, I have no idea, how to get my hands on that subnet thing, how to set it up and all... I hope anyone around here can help me with that since it's really starting to freak me out.

If you need any more information don't hesitate to ask.

And please don't get me wrong. But I don't want to buy accessories. I'd like to know if what I'm trying to achieve is at all possible and if it is, then how.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
If you know a good tutorial that answers my question, I'd be happy to see it.

EDIT 2:
My network setup is as following:

**Router:**
IP: 192.168.178.1
DHCP: 192.168.178.211 to 192.168.178.255 (I know it's unusual, but I like it this way.)
Subnet: 255.255.255.0

**Notebook:**
WiFi IP: 192.168.178.231

Wired IP: I don't know what to put here
Wired Routes: I don't know what to put here
Wired DNS Server and Search Domain: I don't know what to put here
Wired Gateway: I guess it should be 192.168.178.1 (Correct?)

Comment: You’re wasting your time if your problem can be solved with a wired connection. If a wired connection is not feasible, get a WiFi card for your PC.

Answer (score 0):

When you share the connection on the Notebook, you have configured the notebook to deliver an IP address to the wired PC. You need to ensure that:

- The IP address given to the wired PC is on the SAME subnet as your router
- The notebook correctly routes all traffic via the default gateway (your router)

So rather than making a second subnet, the easiest approach is to ensure everything is on a single subnet. So if your router is 192.168.1.1 and gives out DHCP addresses from 192.168.1.100-200 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, the address of your wired pc needs to be something like 192.168.1.210 (e.g. outside the DHCP range but inside the subnet). You can set that manually if needed.

Exactly how to do this depends on the Linux distro and how you've configured both the network and the sharing.

Comment: That won’t work because you can’t bridge WiFi to Ethernet. At best, connectivity will be available for either device intermittently.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I tried that and still can't get it to work. In Xubuntu, when I select "Shared to other computers" in my wired connection settings, I can't add routes or anything manually. So I tried with the config files using nano. But how do I set up the routes (in general?) where must it point? Can you give an example for that? See my edit for addresses in my network...

Comment: @Daniel B - I should have reloaded before commenting. So, why doesn't this work? The bridging I mean... It would work the other way round, wouldn't it? As an AP? Or would this also only share the internet connection but not grant network access?

Comment: @armin You can't bridge Wi-Fi to Ethernet because the wireless access point will only talk to the MAC address (of the wireless NIC) that associated with it. It will consider the MAC address of the wired NIC invalid, since that address never associated and can't associate.

Comment: Bridging is not possible because the physical layer is different, 802.3 vs 802.11. You’ll get an error when you attempt to do it. A WiFi AP expects a station to have a single static MAC address. [Read this section](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode#bridged_client_mode_issues) in the OpenWrt wiki to learn more.

Comment: I think you have to configure it manually. There is no absolute reason you can't do what you want to but you need to configure the notebook as a *router* to route from the wifi connection to the wired and visa versa.